# WPF creating new sub-menu when I don't want it to?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm working with a WPF menu and unfortunately whenever I go to set an Icon in Visual Studio designer I receive an exception error.

To work around this I'm trying to set the icon with XAML code, I have the following:

```
<Menu Height="23" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" Opacity="1">
    <MenuItem Header="Help">
        <MenuItem Header="About"> 
            <Image Source="Images/Help.png" />
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Unfortunately this creates the following scenario:

[image]

I've tried googling the issue but can't see where my XAML has gone wrong. I know this is simple, but I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
<Menu Height="23" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" Opacity="1">
    <MenuItem Header="Help">
        <MenuItem Header="About">
            <MenuItem.Icon>
                <Image Source="Images/Help.png" />
            </MenuItem.Icon>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: I think so - but the image is full size - what sizes should I be setting it to so this would show normally? Basically what I'm trying to do is display a menu much like Visual Studio - Icons in the left column, description in the right

Comment: Use `<Image Width="24" Height="24"` or use a thumbnail.

Comment: Did the trick! Thank-you very much! You are a king amongst men.

Answer (score 1):

do you want something like this?

```
<Menu Height="23" Name="menu1" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" Opacity="1">
  <MenuItem Header="Help">
   <MenuItem>
    <MenuItem.Header>
      <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="Images/Help.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="About" />
      </StackPanel>
     </MenuItem.Header>
    </MenuItem>
   </MenuItem>
 </Menu>
```

Comment: This is closer but I'm trying to show the icon next to about (in the column on the left). Basically - the menu would be the same as Visual Studio with icons on the left of the text.